# Trying to sum a finite series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

I've tried to solve a financial mathematical task and I need to sum such a finite series:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{6}\frac{1.05^{3k+1}}{1.05^{3k+1}-1}$$

So I decided that maybe I'll try to find a solution to :
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{x^{j}}{x^{j}-1}$$
My first idea was to $+1$ and $-1$ in the numerator. So I would get:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}1+\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{1}{x^{j}-1}$$
But either it is not the right approach or I just don't see how to continue it. Could somebody help me with the problem? I know I could just put the first formula to mathematica, but I couldn't do such a thing during an exam or a test, so I would like to find a paper answer.

EDIT:

I also need to find a sum of:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{jx^{j}}{x^{j}-1}$$
But that's even harder.

Comment: For your first sum you can use mathemateca (or walframalpha online), for your sum it's equal to :$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\frac{1}{1-x^j}=\sum_{i=0}^{+\infty} k(i)x^i $$ where $k(i)$ is the number of divisors of $i$

Comment: How do you know? Could you tell me where I can find a proof of it? :)

Comment: @Elaqqad The number of divisors that are at most $n$, actually.

Comment: @Novsar Why not try to prove it yourself, now that you have the result?

Comment: @Novasar I'm sorry, $k(i)$ the number of divisors of $i$ less than $n$, (another mistake in my comment: start the sum from $j=1$ not $j=0$ )

Comment: And if really the trouble is to compute the first sum, try $$17.316138190844397153823241151647\ldots$$

Comment: It's not a problem, I can compute it in mathematica or somewhere else, but I would like to know if there's a smarter way. What if n was 100 in the task? Then I wouldn't compute it very fast on a piece of paper, would I? :)

Comment: Sure, then why write that "I've tried to solve a financial mathematical task and I need to sum such a finite series"?

Comment: Well, sorry for not being precise. :) It was just the reason why I started to think about a more general problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{6}\frac{1.05^{3n+1}}{1.05^{3n+1}-1}=\sum_{n=1}^{6}\frac{1}{1-(\frac{20}{21})^{3n+1}}$$
and then use
$$\frac{1}{1-x^m}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty }x^{nm}$$

Comment: I amended an obvious typo--right away--I wish you can bear with my course of action.